# Change querystring parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it supposed to be?

```
var text = $(this).siblings("[type=text]").val();
document.location = "Default.aspx" + "?id=" + text + "&type=" + query;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please tell us what the result needs to be and what the HTML looks like...

Answer (score 2):

The name of the property is `window.location`, not `document.location`. Also, you might want to escape one (or both) of those values using `encodeURIComponent`.

```
window.location = "Default.aspx" +
    "?id=" + encodeURIComponent(text) +
    "&type=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
```